# Creating Frequency Matrix (counting number of items in array) in J

Tags: j

```
>text
┌───────────┬──────────┬───────────┬──────────┬──────────┬─────────┬──────────┬─────────────┬─────────────┬──────────┬───────────────┬──────────┬──────────┬────────────┬─────────────────┬──────────┬──────────┬──────────────┬─────────────┬─────────────┬────...
│speak      │conceal   │terribl    │option    │write     │book     │come      │tuesdai      │matter       │act       │conceal        │catastroph│integr    │depart      │justic           │put       │wai       │choic         │realli       │bad          │opti...
├───────────┼──────────┼───────────┼──────────┼──────────┼─────────┼──────────┼─────────────┼─────────────┼──────────┼───────────────┼──────────┼──────────┼────────────┼─────────────────┼──────────┼──────────┼──────────────┼─────────────┼─────────────┼────...
│trump      │logu      │talk       │entir     │time      │talk     │entir     │time         │discov       │someth    │frequent       │doe       │logu      │thi         │direct           │logu      │direct    │logu          │differ       │direct       │cons...
├───────────┼──────────┼───────────┼──────────┼──────────┼─────────┼──────────┼─────────────┼─────────────┼──────────┼───────────────┼──────────┼──────────┼────────────┼─────────────────┼──────────┼──────────┼──────────────┼─────────────┼─────────────┼────...
│cohen      │lawyer    │object     │taint     │team      │anoth    │unusu     │move         │lawyer       │trump     │file           │emerg     │motion    │court       │sundai           │night     │sai       │presid        │object       │extraordinari│meas...
├───────────┼──────────┼───────────┼──────────┼──────────┼─────────┼──────────┼─────────────┼─────────────┼──────────┼───────────────┼──────────┼──────────┼────────────┼─────────────────┼──────────┼──────────┼──────────────┼─────────────┼─────────────┼────...
│photo      │presid    │trump      │fire      │jame      │comei    │director  │mai          │did          │mean      │end            │comei     │time      │public      │memoir           │higher    │loyalti   │releas        │comei        │featur       │wide...
├───────────┼──────────┼───────────┼──────────┼──────────┼─────────┼──────────┼─────────────┼─────────────┼──────────┼───────────────┼──────────┼──────────┼────────────┼─────────────────┼──────────┼──────────┼──────────────┼─────────────┼─────────────┼────...
│british    │deleg     │organ      │wrote     │twitter   │russia   │syria     │allow        │access       │douma     │unfett         │access    │essenti   │russia      │syria            │cooper    │western   │diplomat      │confirm      │syria        │russ...
├───────────┼──────────┼───────────┼──────────┼──────────┼─────────┼

cleaned_text

    ┌─────┬───────┬───────┬──────┬─────┬────┬────┬───────┬──────┬───┬───────┬──────────┬──────┬──────┬──────┬───┬───┬─────┬──────┬───┬──────┬──────────┬──────┬────┬────┬────┬────────┬─────┬─────┬───────┬───────┬───────┬───────┬───┬─────┬───────┬────┬───────┬──...
    │speak│conceal│terribl│option│write│book│come│tuesdai│matter│act│conceal│catastroph│integr│depart│justic│put│wai│choic│realli│bad│option│catastroph│option│hard│call│tell│congress│thing│chang│clinton│fervent│support│disagre│sai│least│philipp│rein│longtim│tr...
    └─────┴───────┴───────┴──────┴─────┴────┴────┴───────┴──────┴───┴───────┴──────────┴──────┴──────┴──────┴───┴───┴─────┴──────┴───┴──────┴──────────┴──────┴────┴────┴────┴────────┴─────┴─────┴───────┴───────┴───────┴───────┴───┴─────┴───────┴────┴───────┴──...
```

each row of "text" is a news article, and I am trying to figure out the number of each vocab from cleaned_text in each article so that I can create a frequency matrix like this:

```
    art1 art2 art3 ...
mai 4    5    4 
sai 1    0    0
...
```

I am looking e. and E. verbs to count the number of each vocab in each article, but I am having a hard time to use them in this case.

Can anyone help me on this issue??? Thank you!

Comment: Actually I created the matrix, but is there a better way to compute this matrix? (it took several minutes to proceed since #cleaned_text = 39798...)
freqCount =: 3 : '+/"1 (y{cleaned_text) ="1 >text'
]freqMat =: freqCount"0 i.#cleaned_text

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use a slightly different approach. To keep things simple, I will use the example of `p`

```
   p
┌─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┐
│pants│shirt│shirt│hat  │pants│
├─────┼─────┼─────┼─────┼─────┤
│shoes│shoes│socks│pants│shirt│
├─────┼─────┼─────┼─────┼─────┤
│shirt│hat  │pants│shoes│shoes│
├─────┼─────┼─────┼─────┼─────┤
│socks│pants│shirt│shirt│hat  │
├─────┼─────┼─────┼─────┼─────┤
│pants│shoes│shoes│socks│pants│
├─────┼─────┼─────┼─────┼─────┤
│shirt│shirt│hat  │pants│shoes│
└─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┘
```

To get a count of each article of clothing I need to compare each row to the whole vocabulary. I get the whole vocabulary by ravelling (`,`) p and getting the nub (`~.`) This ensures that every possible word in p is accounted for.

```
   ~.@:,p
┌─────┬─────┬───┬─────┬─────┐
│pants│shirt│hat│shoes│socks│
└─────┴─────┴───┴─────┴─────┘
```

Now I will transpose (`|:`) p so that the I can compare each row to the nub using `=/` and finish off with totalling up the sum across each item. `+/@:`

```
   +/@:(|: =/ ~.@,)p
2 2 1 0 0
1 1 0 2 1
1 1 1 2 0
1 2 1 0 1
2 0 0 2 1
1 2 1 1 0
```

Reading these numbers against the nub I see the first row has 2-pants 2-shirts 1-hat 0-shoes and 0-socks and by inspection this is correct. The second row has 1-pant 1-shirt 0-hats 2-shoes and 1-sock and so on...

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yep. Also a good opportunity to use the sadly neglected monad `=`, which does this kind of tabulation for a living, and spares you the effort of calculating the nub for yourself. The one drawback is it works on items, so you’ll have to ravel your table first, tabulate it, then unravel, like so: `|: (-{:$p) +/\”1  = ,p` (or `|:@(-@{:@$ +/\”1 =@,) p`) Instinctually, I feel there might be a way to at once simplify and make the result more elegant through a factoring out of that `”1` and final `|:`, possibly by bringing the transpose up earlier and using a judicious or more intelligent LHA.